# How do I get this variable to be defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, partial

I have this code:

```
  <% @registered_friends.each do |friend| %>    
      <li><%= render 'profiles/fb_follow_form' %></li>
  <% end %>
```

It renders a partial in a different directory with this line:

```
<% if current_user != nil && current_user.following?(friend) %>
```

However my app is telling me that `friend` is undefined? How do I give myself access to the variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `<li><%= render 'profiles/fb_follow_form' %></li>`

to `<li><%= render 'profiles/fb_follow_form', :friend => friend %></li>`

should do it